# Different behavior of same function defined at two places: symbol's value as variable is void

Tags: lexical-scoping

I implemented a couple of extra functions that work with [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) and have been keeping them in my [dotfiles](https://github.com/myTerminal/dotfiles) as they are not yet a part of the original package. When the functions are defined in the file [packages.el](https://github.com/myTerminal/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/myTerminal/packages.el) after line number 130, all lexical bindings work well.

However, when I tried extracting the two functions into a separate file [here](https://github.com/myTerminal/dotfiles/blob/cdbca02352a8a970c67659ebfcee865c2d915cbb/.emacs.d/local-packages/projectile-extras.el) and `require` them somewhere down the line, it throws an error saying "Symbol’s value as variable is void: text-to-search". Apparently the closures are not getting created correctly.

```
(defun projectile-find-all-occurrences (&optional arg)
  "List all occurrences of the text being searched using completion.
With a prefix argument ARG prompts you for a directory on which to run search in."
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((text-to-search (read-string
                          (projectile-prepend-project-name "Find all: ")
                          (projectile-symbol-or-selection-at-point)))
         (directory (if arg
                        (file-name-as-directory
                         (read-directory-name "Find in directory: "))
                      (projectile-project-root)))
         (file-to-search (projectile-files-with-string text-to-search directory)))
    (projectile-completing-read
     "All occurrences: "
     (reduce #'append
             (mapcar (lambda (file)
                       (with-temp-buffer
                         (insert-file-contents file)
                         (let ((lines (split-string (buffer-string) "\n")))
                           (cl-remove-if nil
                                         (mapcar (lambda (line)
                                                   (let ((present-in-linep (search text-to-search line)))
                                                     (cond (present-in-linep (concat (cadr (split-string file (projectile-project-root)))
                                                                                     " => line "
                                                                                     (number-to-string (1+ (cl-position line lines)))))
                                                           (t nil))))
                                                 lines)))))
                     file-to-search))
     :action `(lambda (item)
                (let ((file (car (split-string item " => line ")))
                      (line-number (string-to-number (cadr (split-string item " => line ")))))
                  (find-file (expand-file-name file ,(projectile-project-root)))
                  (beginning-of-buffer)
                  (forward-line (1- line-number))
                  (search-forward text-to-search)
                  (set-mark-command nil)
                  (search-backward text-to-search)
                  (run-hooks 'projectile-find-file-hook))))))
```

I have tried too many things to finally give up and cannot think of any way to make it work myself now. Seems to be that I am missing something too obvious to notice or is it...?

Comment: A question is more useful if the meaning is in the question itself. Here, it is impossible to know what the question is really about without following links. It doesn't help to refer readers to whole files (including dotfiles, no less). This question could benefit from being self-contained and pared down to what's relevant. Please see [How To Ask](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is not my first question on StackExchange and I have asked better questions earlier. I have been so frustrated with this problem of mine and after spending so much time to figure this out myself, I was not in a state to think more on breaking the scope of the question down to plain text, hence a question full of references. I certainly know how to ask a question, though I have not been my best this time.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking.  Is it your intent that [`(projectile-project-root)`](https://github.com/myTerminal/dotfiles/blob/cdbca02352a8a970c67659ebfcee865c2d915cbb/.emacs.d/local-packages/projectile-extras.el#L91) be a compile-time constant ?

Comment: @politza, I do not think I need it that way now. I remember I had issues with binding that expression earlier and ended up putting it that way. Thanks for pointing out though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *quoted* `text-to-search` in those `:action` forms (because the entire form is quoted), which therefore is not the same thing as your lexically-bound variable; so when those forms are called as functions, they are looking for a dynamic scope variable of that name.

So that looks like a bug no matter where the functions were defined. Presumably it was being masked in your original scenario.

Comment: It seems to work when I replace `text-to-search` with `,@(list text-to-search)`, something around what it shows here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html, but I am not convinced with creating a single element list for the purpose, any better ways to achieve that?

Comment: @myTerminal: I think `,@(list foo)` should always be the same as just `,foo`.

Comment: @npostavs: `,foo` does not seem to work, as I have tried it before

Comment: @myTerminal: I can't think of any case where the equivalence doesn't hold. As Drew suggested, posting a minimal example would be helpful.

Comment: @npostavs, `,foo` works, I missed to update another reference earlier (I had two of them) and made myself think that it did not work, Thanks.

Comment: @myTerminal, you seem to still be quoting the function forms? Is there a reason for that? I would suggest not quoting, and using the lexically-bound variable.

Comment: @phils, I think the quoting is required as it has been done in the original code in projectile. Also, I have fixed the file references to a specific version.

Comment: Quoting lambdas used to be needed when there was no lexical-binding, in order to splice values into them.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing instances of `text-to-search` with `,text-to-search` solves the problem.

```
(lambda (item)
  (let ((file (car (split-string item " => line ")))
        (line-number (string-to-number (cadr (split-string item " => line ")))))
    (find-file (expand-file-name file (projectile-project-root)))
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (forward-line (1- line-number))
    (search-forward ,text-to-search)
    (set-mark-command nil)
    (search-backward ,text-to-search)
    (run-hooks 'projectile-find-file-hook)))
```

Comment: This is not the way to create a closure (though perhaps that wasn't actually your intention)

Comment: I'm still learning Emacs Lisp and this is apparently the only way it works for me. Any better alternatives are appreciated! :)

Comment: Remove the apostrophe in front of the lambda and all commas inside.

Comment: Actually that seems to work.

Comment: [(elisp) Lexical Binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html) has an example of creating a closure.

Comment: @myTerminal: ...which was my earlier suggestion -- *not* quoting, and using the lexical variable.